# How to modify for the new info when i change the option in selected using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

My objective is, when i change the year, then the info of the table changes to that year.

I can get all i need with the functions i have (with this i mean to get the year using javascript), the only think i need is how to make the info changes.
I tried earlier using a boolean to if the option changes then the info will change, but again, only works apllying the binding more than 1 time.

 Since its not possible to apply bindings mulltiple times i run out of ideas.
(**New to knockout**)

**HTML**
 
'''

```
<div class="col-md-3 container" style="margin:auto">
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1951">1951</option>
        <option value="1953">1953</option>
        <option value="1955">1955</option>
        <option value="1957">1957</option>
        <option value="1959">1959</option>
        <option value="1961">1961</option>
        <option value="1963">1963</option>

    </select>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 container">
        <center><h3>Classificação dos Pilotos</h3></center>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-1">Position</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Points</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: DS">
                <tr data-bind="visible: $index() < 5">
                    <th scope="row" style="vertical-align:auto" data-bind="text: Position">#1</th>
                    <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Points"></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="buttonD" type="button" class="btn btn-light container" style="margin:auto">Mostrar toda a classificação</button>
    </div>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/knockout-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

'''

**JS**

```
var year;

var triger = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
});

function myFunction() {
    year = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    triger = true;
    console.log("HERE" + year)
}

var vm = function () {

    console.log("IMready!");

    var self = this;
    self.baseUri = ko.observable('http://192.168.160.58/Formula1/api/Statistics/Season')

    self.DS = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.activate = function (year) {

        console.log('CALL: getDrivers...');

        var composedUri = self.baseUri() + "?year=" + year;

        ajaxHelper(composedUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {

            console.log(data.DriverStandings);

            self.DS(data.DriverStandings);

            console.log("HEEEEERRREEEE")

            console.log(self.DS)

        });
    };

    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
        });
    }

    if (triger == true) {
        console.log("ACTIVATE")
        self.activate(year);
    }
    else if (triger == false) {
        console.log("ACTIVATE BY DEFAULT")
        self.activate(2021);
    }

}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `value` binding to store the selected option from your dropdown in your viewmodel.

You can then `subscribe` to changes of the value to load the data.

In the snippet below I've simplified your example to show how it'd work.

```js
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  // Data
  self.years = [ 1951, 1953, 1955, 1957, 1959, 1961, 1963 ];

  // State
  self.selectedYear = ko.observable(null);
  self.DS = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  // Methods
  self.activate = function(year) {
    if (!year) {
      self.DS([]);
      return;
    }
    
    var composedUri = year; // TODO: put back your URL

    ajaxHelper(composedUri, 'GET').then(function(data) {
      self.DS(data.DriverStandings);
    });
  };

  // Auto-update
  self.selectedYear.subscribe(self.activate);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());


// TODO: put back your real ajax call
function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
  return Promise.resolve({
    DriverStandings: [
      { Position: "#1", Name: `${uri}’s winner`, Points: 9001 },
      { Position: "#2", Name: `${uri}’s runner up`, Points: 999 },
      { Position: "#3", Name: `${uri}’s loser`, Points: 42 },
    ]
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="
  value: selectedYear,
  options: years,
  optionsCaption: 'Open the select menu'">
</select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: DS">
    <tr data-bind="visible: $index() < 5">
      <td data-bind="text: Position">#1</td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Points"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: There's a potential problem in the example above. When a user changes the dropdown's value faster than your ajax call resolves, multiple requests will be running at the same time. One easy way of protecting against that is to disable the UI when data is loading:

```js
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  // Data
  self.years = [ 1951, 1953, 1955, 1957, 1959, 1961, 1963 ];

  // State
  self.selectedYear = ko.observable(null);
  self.DS = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.loading = ko.observable(false);
  
  // Methods
  self.activate = function(year) {
    if (!year) {
      self.DS([]);
      return;
    }
    
    var composedUri = year; // TODO: put back your URL

    self.loading(true);
    
    ajaxHelper(composedUri, 'GET')
      .then(function(data) {
        self.DS(data.DriverStandings);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        self.loading(false);
      });
  };

  // Auto-update
  self.selectedYear.subscribe(self.activate);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());


// TODO: put back your real ajax call
function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
  // Fake a slow call
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(
      () => res({
        DriverStandings: [
          { Position: "#1", Name: `${uri}’s winner`, Points: 9001 },
          { Position: "#2", Name: `${uri}’s runner up`, Points: 999 },
          { Position: "#3", Name: `${uri}’s loser`, Points: 42 },
        ]
      }),
      500
    )
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="
  disable: loading,
  value: selectedYear,
  options: years,
  optionsCaption: 'Open the select menu'">
</select>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- ko if: loading -->
  <tbody><tr><td colspan="3">Loading...</td></tr></tbody>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko ifnot: loading -->
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: DS">
    <tr data-bind="visible: $index() < 5">
      <td data-bind="text: Position">#1</td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Points"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

Comment: But,, what if u want to add data-bind="foreach: List" to the select and use <option data-bind:" Text: Year"></<option> where this is another API. In this case we cant do what u said, rigth? Are there any other options?

Comment: If your options are objects, you can use the `optionsText` binding. For example: `<select data-bind="options: List, optionsText: 'Year'"></select>`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), it has some great examples.